# C allocation problems: function which converts decimal numbers to bits

Tags: c, memory-management, malloc, heap-memory, allocation

I'm trying to make a code which converts some decimal numbers to bits.
There are more simple ways to reach this result but I'm poking around and joking with memory in C.

```
int ** decimalToBits(int *number,int size){
    int **bits = (int **)malloc(sizeof(*bits)*size), i = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < size; j++) {
        int * temp = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int));
        while (number[j] >= 1) {
            temp[i++] = number[j] % 2;
            number[j] /= 2;
            realloc(temp, sizeof(int)); 
        }
        printf("\n");
        bits[j] = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int)*i);
        for (int k = i-1; k >= 0; k--){
            bits[j][k] = temp[k];
            printf("%d" ,bits[j][k]);
        }
        i = 0;
    }
    return bits;
}
```

I'm having some allocation problems, first of all I'm going to explain the idea:

I pass to the function multiple numbers, so for example:

```
int numbers[2] = {23,73};
decimalToBits(numbers,2);
```

Each converted number will be stored in **bits double pointer, so bits[0] will contain the number 23 converted, and bits[1] will contain 73 converted as well.

The problem shows up when I do `bits[j] = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int)*i);` call,
because this seems to let the temp pointer to be overwritten with some random numbers. In fact if I remove the `bits[j] = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int)*i);` and `bits[j][k] = temp[k];` lines and I replace `printf("%d" ,bits[j][k]);` with `printf("%d" ,temp[k]);`
the code seems to have a good behavior, and it gives me the correct output:

```
10111
1001001
```

I also noticed that allocating the `bits[j] = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int)*8);` externally from the `for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)` loop let the code works. So why this allocation problem occurs when declared just like the above code and what's the best way to solve it?

Comment: "Convert decimal numbers to bits"? An `int` **is** bits...?!?

Comment: @DevSolar Each bit is considered an integer but that's not the point

Comment: Well, clearly the naked `realloc(temp, sizeof(int)); ` is wrong. That function has a return value for a reason. And frankly those arguments are near-nonsense anyway.

Comment: @WhozCraig: Good catch, and probably the answer. I didn't even get that far before being utterly confused about the purpose of it all. :-D

Comment: @WhozCraig near-nonsense is a very kind description.